# Calculating Lebesgue-Integral of Function over Annulus

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I came across this exercise in 'Analysis $3$' by Otto Forster. I will have measure and integration theory in my 3rd semester so right now, I am not really informed about the preliminaries, to solve such a Problem, yet I would like to know, how one would approach and solve such a Problem. Unfortunately, the book does not provide a solution to this problem.

Here is the question:

Calculate (determine) the Lebesgue-Integral of the Function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x = (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1x_2||x||^{-1}$, over the annulus $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 \leq ||x|| \leq 2 \}$.

Comment: $\mathbb R\,\,?$

Comment: Do you see an anti-symmetry that allows you to say without a calculation what that integral must be? Hint: in $\mathbb R^2$ there are four quadrants.

Comment: @KurtG. could you elaborate on that? I would be interested in the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @bungeegum Elaborating is boring :) . How does $f$ in the first quadrant relate to $f$ in the second? And how in the other two quadrants? What is then the average of $f$ ?